# Quero rotacionar o meu Eixo x porque toda vez que faço o meu gráfico, os nomes do eixo X se sobrepõe. (sou iniciante), Alguém pode me ajudar pf?

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

```
tabela = pd.read_excel("Pastelaria Relatório Original.xlsx")
TN=tabela
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Refri = sns.barplot('Refrigerantes', 'Q.R.V.', data=NT)
for i in Refri.patches:
     Refri.annotate(i.get_height(),
                  (i.get_x() + i.get_width() / 2, i.get_height()),
                  ha='center',
                  va='baseline',
                  fontsize=12,
                  color='black',
                  xytext=(0, 1),
                  textcoords='offset points')


plt.savefig('testerefri.pdf', format='pdf', dpi=300, transparent=True, bbox_inches='tight')

plt.show(Refri)
```

Answer (score 0):

Já consegui resolver o problema, caso alguém tenha a mesma dúvida eu usei o seguinte código:

```
plt.xticks(rotation=-90)
```

Ficaram na vertical.